# Store load canceled after 30 seconds

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, extjs-stores

I've problem with store load. Extjs cancel load after 30 seconds. Is there some parameters or something else to increase store load time?

Here is example of store:

```
  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'store_model',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'data/backend.php',              
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            }

        },          
        autoLoad : true
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

`Ext.Ajax.timeout = 60000;`

Comment: I just added   "timeout : 120000" in store proxy

Answer (score 3):

This allows to change the timeout only for one store:

```
store.proxy.setTimeout(60000);
```

Tested in ExtJs 6.2

Answer (score 2):

store is a declaration for the calls for the ApiServer that links a model view, to a server model data access.

First you have to define wich of the methods linked to a call you will use
the types are "uxproxy", "ajax", "html"

when you use them, you can set a linked call timeout to the current,

you have to call by using callback :

```
function(response, success ){
}
```

but what really happens is that when you call

```
store.load(elemn, {callback:function(contractId,success) {              
    if (success) {
        ...
    }
})
```

this call by the moment of the code execution, reads a property loaded to the DOM that change it timesout to 30000 ms

so.. you have to override the property. the code posted before doesn´t work if you don't do this

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, { timeout: 600000 });
```

(this will override de default property thats close your call)

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.action.Action, { timeout: 600 });
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

The topic is too old but FYI who want to do the quicky trick.

The default of Ajax call in Sencha is [30000 milliseconds (30 seconds)](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/src/Server.js.html#Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-timeout)
So, you have to set a config to the default behavior in the `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax`, for example, 60s, like:

```
Ext.define('Core.data.proxy.WrapperAjax',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    alias: 'proxy.wrapperAjax',
    config: {
        timeout: 60000
    }
    ...
});
```

or overwrite in `Ext.data.Store` proxy like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    proxy: {
        ...
        timeout: 60000, 
        ...
    },
});
```

Comment: Checked at v6.2, works! Also global desision can be used: Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {proxy: {timeout: 10 000}});